# Lazy evaluation for logging in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, lazy-evaluation

When you have values than are expensive to compute, a common pattern you see in logging frameworks is

```
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
    String value = expensiveComputation();
    log.debug("value: {}", value);
}
```

Since Java 8 added lambdas, it'd be nice to do:

```
log.debug("value: {}", (Supplier<String>) this::expensiveComputation);
```

Which *almost* works because the logging framework will do `toString()` on the parameter. The problem is `toString()` on `Supplier` is the implementation in `Object`.

Is there a way to supply something that's evaluated lazily to `Logger` methods? It would almost just be a `Supplier` with a default `toString()` that calls `get()`.

Comment: If your logging framework does `toString` then it cannot be used with lambdas (without a wrapper class for lambda).

Comment: "... because the logging framework will do toString() on the parameter." Why would the logging-factory do that if the parameter is of type `Supplier<String>`? There is not need to call `toString()` on a `String`

Comment: which logging framework are you using?

Comment: Also, if you use async logging, the result of `expensiveComputation` may change between the log call and actual write. And if you don't use async logging, you have a larger problem.

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer slf4j

Comment: I'm surprised https://jira.qos.ch/browse/SLF4J-371 hasn't made it into slf4j yet. That would indeed be very convenient

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer When it does, that'd probably be the answer to this question.

Comment: log.debug("qwe", ()->{return "";}); 

I get such error Cannot resolve method 'debug' in 'Logger' 

I use lombok and @Slf4j annotation. 

Maven: org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22 (lombok-1.18.22.jar) 

What should I do?

Answer (score 20):

To pass an argument that will executed in a lazy way the `String` computation, you have to pass a `Supplier` and not a `String`.
The method that you invoke should have this signature :

```
void debug(Supplier<?> msgSupplier, Throwable t)
```

You could introduce this utility method in your own utility class.
**But you should not need to do that** as recent logging frameworks such as Log4j2 provides this feature out of the box.

For example, [org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html) provides overloaded methods to log that accept a `Supplier`.
For [example](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html#debug(org.apache.logging.log4j.util.MessageSupplier,%20java.lang.Throwable)) :

> `void debug(MessageSupplier msgSupplier, Throwable t)`
>
> Logs a message (only to be constructed if the logging level is the
>   DEBUG level) including the stack trace of the Throwable t passed as
>   parameter. The MessageSupplier may or may not use the MessageFactory
>   to construct the Message.
>
> `Parameters`:
>
> `msgSupplier` - A function, which when called, produces the desired log
>   message.
>
> `t` - the exception to log, including its stack trace.

From Log4j2 documentation :

> **Java 8 lambda support for lazy logging**
>
> In release 2.4, the Logger interface added support for lambda
>   expressions. This allows client code to lazily log messages without
>   explicitly checking if the requested log level is enabled. For
>   example, previously you would write:
>
> ```
> if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
>     logger.trace("Some long-running operation returned {}", expensiveOperation());
> }
> ```
>
> With Java 8 you can achieve the same effect with a lambda expression.
>   You no longer need to explicitly check the log level:
>
> ```
> logger.trace("Some long-running operation returned {}", 
>               () ->    expensiveOperation());
> ```

Comment: The very last line is what I was looking for. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: log.debug("qwe", ()->{return "";});
I get such error Cannot resolve method 'debug' in 'Logger' 

I use lombok and @Slf4j annotation.
Maven: org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22 (lombok-1.18.22.jar)

What should I do?

Answer (score 10):

A small helper object will allow you to do what you want:

```
public class MessageSupplier {
    private Supplier<?> supplier;

    public MessageSupplier(Supplier<?> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return supplier.get().toString();
    }

    public static MessageSupplier msg(Supplier<?> supplier) {
        return new MessageSupplier(supplier);
    }
}
```

Or in Kotlin:

```kotlin
class MessageSupplier(supplier: Supplier<?>) {
    override fun toString() = supplier.get().toString()
}

fun msg(supplier: Supplier<?>) = MessageSupplier(supplier)
```

Then, with a static import of `msg`:

```
log.debug("foo: {}", msg(this::expensiveComputation));
```

Comment: This is a simple and effective approach with adding more dependencies.

Comment: Nice solution. But formally there is no guarantee toString would be called only once. So there is a chance an expensive calculation would be run multiple times. That could potentially be even worse than provide to logger already built String (that could be forgot) instead of Supplier.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly you can't even use something like this

`interface LazyString {
   String toString();
}`

as a functional interface

The only way I found so far is via anonymous classes.

`Object o = new Object() {
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return myExpensiveComputation();
   }
};
System.out.printf("%s", o);`

Answer (score 1):

Since you revealed you use SLF4J which still does not support this at the core, this might come in handy if you code in Kotlin (which you can with JDK 8) :

```kotlin
fun Logger.info( provider: () -> String ) { if (this.isInfoEnabled) this.info(provider.invoke())
fun Logger.debug( provider: () -> String ) { if (this.isDebugEnabled) this.debug(provider.invoke())
fun Logger.trace( provider: () -> String ) { if (this.isTraceEnabled) this.trace(provider.invoke())
```

Usage:

```kotlin
log.trace { "State dump: " + expensiveLongSerialisation(state) }
```

Source: My Gist :)  https://gist.github.com/OndraZizka/a7381b8cd86f734bc3b6bf9e528a01ad

Comment: Then the line number will be broken

Answer (score 0):

> Which *almost* works because the logging framework will do `toString()` on the parameter.

This statement isn't correct. If you step into the `debug`/`info`/whatever method, you'll find this implementation:

```
public void log(Level level, Supplier<String> msgSupplier) {
    if (!isLoggable(level)) {
        return;
    }
    LogRecord lr = new LogRecord(level, msgSupplier.get());
    doLog(lr);
}
```

If the `level` isn't met, the `Supplier` isn't even used.

Comment: Which logging framework are you looking at? I'm looking at slf4j for the API and Logback for the implementation.

Comment: This snippet is taken from `java.util.logging.Logger`. I'll see if I can dig up logback's implementation

Answer (score 0):

For `java.util.logging` and Java 8+ you can also use this **lazy** and handy notation:

```
LOGGER.fine(() -> "Message1: "  + longComputation1() + ". Message2: " + longComputation2());
```

`longComputation1()` and `longComputation2()` will be called lazy - i.e. only when needed.

Comment: how to define LOGGER ?